# Castle windsor and IHttpHandler and IHttpHandlerFactory

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, castle, ihttphandler

I'm developing a RIA application where there is javascript on the client (i'm using Ext) and .NET on the server, for json-rpc I'm using Jayrock which is a nice library (at least for me) as it is simple and works well, Ive used it in the past.

Jayrock uses Web Handlers to serve the json-rpc request, you code a class that implements IHttpHandler and derives from a Jayrock class with some attributes, and it does the rest to provide a javascript class to the browser to do its magic.

Now, normally web handlers will have parameter-less constructors, but I want to use DI on them, and use windsor to resolve the dependencies for me

So, I will have some class like the following

```
    public class VistaEntidadSimpleServer :  JsonRpcVistaHandler ,IHttpHandler
{
    public VistaEntidadSimpleServer(ISomeDependecy someObject)
    {
                 someObject.doSomething();

    }


    [JsonRpcMethod("Aceptar")]
    public string Aceptar (IVista vista)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }


    [JsonRpcMethod("Cancelar")]
    public string Cancelar (IVista vista)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }


    public IVista CargarDatos(IVista vista)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

So, now the problem is how to get windsor in the middle to do the resolving. After searching around, and from what it seems to do spring, I think I can give a try to IHttpHandlerFactory, and code something like this

```
    public class CastleWindsorHttpHandlerFactory : IHttpHandlerFactory
{
    public CastleWindsorHttpHandlerFactory ()
    {
        if (container==null)
        container=(IWindsorContainer)HttpRuntime.Cache.Get("Container");
    }

    #region IHttpHandlerFactory implementation

    public IHttpHandler GetHandler (HttpContext context, string requestType, string url, string pathTranslated)
    {
        return container.Resolve<IHttpHandler>(url);
    }

    public void ReleaseHandler (IHttpHandler handler)
    {
        container.Release(handler);
    }

    #endregion

    private static IWindsorContainer container=null;
}
```

Configuring the web app to use the factory for ashx files, and creating the container in global.asax, configuring the handlers with the url as ids, and registering the containter into the web cache.

Do you think this is a nice solution?, or is there something I am missing here, is there another way to get web handlers resolved by the container?

Thanks in advancce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing the container in cache, implement `IContainerAccessor` in your global HttpApplication to reference your container. No need to store a reference in `CastleWindsorHttpHandlerFactory`.

Other than that, it looks good.

Comment: I'm having a problem following your suggestion. I don't know how to access the container from the ReleaseHandler method of the IHttpHandlerFactory. In the GetHandler method you get a reference to the HttpContext passed in as an argument (and thus a reference to the HttpApplication/IcontainerAccessor instance), but that is not the case in the ReleaseHandler method. When I try to use HttpContext.Current from the ReleaseHandler the WebApp just dies silently. Do you have any suggestions as to how I get a hold of the IContainerAccessor in the ReleaseHandler method?

Comment: @JohannesH create a new question or post it in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/castle-project-users

Comment: Ok, I will. Though I will say I solved it by storing the container in a local field from the GetHandler method. However it seems a little brittle since I'm not sure the methods are always called in succession... It's not really documented.